# How to exclude an enumeration value in XML file using XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Is it possible to specify the value of a tag or attribute **should not be like** *some_value* ?

I have a strange requirement, where the xsd isn't aware of the values being sent to it. The value of that particular tag can be a string with any value **except one value**  ( say `data_migration`).

The sender should be acknowledged with the error, if that particular value is sent.

Is it possible to specify this restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no regex expert, but this simpleType makes everything starting with `data_migration` invalid.

```
<xs:simpleType name="notDataMigration">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="^(?!data_migration).*" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can specifically exclude a value. I'm not sure if this helps, but you can create two separate enumerations and then create the union of the enumerations.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="IncludedEnumType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="pending" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="in_process" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="failed" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="unknown" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="ExcludedEnumType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="data_migration" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="CombinedEnumType">
  <xsd:union memberTypes="IncludedEnumType ExcludedEnumType" />
</xsd:simpleType>
```

You would use either `IncludedEnumType` or `CombinedEnumType` as necessary. Using the `IncludedEnumType` would obviously excluded the values in `ExcludedEnumType`.

This approach uses Solution 2 from this [article by IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-extenum/).

Comment: helpful but not in this case ;) so +1.