# XSD: Restricting an already existing enumeration with XSD as the default namespace

Tags: xml, enums, xsd

I have a web-service defined by an XSD. The interface itself contains several operations where some of of the operations use the same enumeration in their request/response messages.
However, in one of the requests I want to limit the possible input values to a sub-set of the enumeration. I have tried something similar to the xml below but failed. Should this be possible? Is there any other solution or do I have to define a new enumeration for this?

```
<element>
    <simpleType>
        <restriction base="myEnum">
            <enumeration value="A"/>
            <enumeration value="B"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType
</element>
<simpleType name="myEnum">
    <restriction base="xsd:string">
        <enumeration value="A"/>
        <enumeration value="B"/>
        <enumeration value="C"/>
        <enumeration value="D"/>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507806/how-to-exclude-an-enumeration-value-in-xml-file-using-xsd).  You could try creating two enums for each use case, and then taking the union of them for places where you already have all values.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question would be a lot easier to answer if you provided a complete, self-contained, reproducible example.  Since you don't provide a complete schema and don't quote exactly what error you're getting, any answer must be based on speculation about the information you didn't provide.  Do better next time, OK?

If your extract from the schema document is correct, then either the problem is a namespace issue, or the problem is being obscured by a namespace issue.  Your simpleType, restriction, and enumeration elements are not prefixed, which suggests that you have declared the XSD namespace as the default namespace.  (Your reference to xsd:string in the definition of myEnum, on the other hand, suggests that you have bound the XSD namespace to the prefix 'xsd'.  Perhaps you've done both.)  The reference to myEnum, in the `base` attribute of your derived type, is unqualified, which means it is interpreted as being in the XSD namespace:  {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}myEnum.  Since there is no type named myEnum in the XSD namespace, you are probably getting a base-type-not-found error.

If your schema has a target namespace, you need to use a prefixed QName to refer to myEnum in that namespace.  If it has no target namespace, then declaring a default namespace is probably not a good idea, as it makes it impossible for you to refer to any of the types you define in your schema.